# Calling APIs for an application using Onelogin for authentication?

Tags: onelogin

My company has several apps that use onelogin for central auth.  I'd like to automate some actions against those applications.  I've dug through the onelogin docs and am unsure how authentication works via API.

All the API calls in their documentation require generating API credentials (which requires logging in as account owner or admin).

I just want to provide end onelogin user credentials and access the underderlying application APIs with their permissions.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Are you all apps using asp.net?

Answer (score 1):

OneLogin doesn't support user-level API credentials.

However, we have a roadmap item (hopefully completing in the next few weeks) for an Auth Only credential. This would only allow access to the authentication endpoints, however.

What actions were you looking at performing via the APIs, if nothing else this will help us decide which APIs should offer user-level credentials.

Comment: 1. Giving me a list of apps and their endpoints. 
2. Generate a SAML token for an app.


I was able to get it to work by debugging the requests flow and writing a python script to perform login as a user.  But APIs would be nice.